# iOS and Windows Docking Station

Tags: display, dock

I have a Lenovo laptop with USB-C charger and an iPad Pro 2021 which I would like to connect to two Dell monitors with HDMI input. I’m looking for an adapter or docking station which is suitable for my devices. Would you be able to give us some recommendations? I’m not a graphics designer and just need some basic connection, preferring the most inexpensive solution.

Comment: When you say two monitors, is it one monitor each for the Lenovo and iPad and two docks?

Answer (score 3):

iPad Pro uses standard thunderbolt but only one external display will work.

- https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/

> Thunderbolt / USB 4 port with support for:
> Charging
> DisplayPort
> Thunderbolt 3 (up to 40Gb/s)
> USB 4 (up to 40Gb/s)
> USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10Gb/s)

I like the CalDigit hubs at the moment, but any high quality one should work for your first display and other accessories like storage, keyboards, networking and such. We have been very disappointed with the “budget” and cheapest USB-C docks at work and pay for reliability to get a good value. Some off brand docks can cause damage or not dissipate heat properly so consider support, shipping and returns when bargain shopping.

The cheapest option for HDMI might be the Apple adapter and then a USB hub for the rest…

- USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter - https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MUF82AM/A

We also like the newer displays that provide thunderbolt natively but that’s an entirely different question I think.